# Is it possible to remove a class definition from Python?

Tags: python, class

Is it possible to remove a class definition from a running instance of Python?

I have a Python interpreter built into my C++ that I'd like to add and remove classes depending on the current state of the application.  For example, if I have a Menu hierarchy that has a corresponding class defined for that menu, I'd like to remove that class if the menu is not visible.

One possible solution is to put the class in a module and unload that module ([How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)), but I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Comment: Could you add your main goal for doing something like this?  Is it to keep memory usage down, for example?  The reason being is: this seems like needless complexity to me :), so I'd like to know the use case you found where doing this is actually useful.

Comment: I'm also curious about the use case.

Comment: FWIW, one use case is that you have `reload()`ed a module - say, because you are iterating on a Jupyter notebook, and are also changing the modules - and you have a class defined in the notebook that inherits from classes in that module. This seems to be the only way to fix up the inheritance structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `del` on the reference to the class.

```
>>> class Example(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> Example
<class '__main__.Example'>
>>> del Example
>>> Example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Example' is not defined
```

Comment: I think there is a long-running “feature” that, even when the running program has no references to a class, its memory is not released for the duration of the program.